# Событие при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба

Tags: html, javascript

Мне надо добиться того, чтоб при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба автоматически выполнялся определённый javascript. Как этого добиться?

p.s. хорошо бы ещё иметь возможность узнать на сколько увеличили/уменьшили масштаб

Comment: Увеличении/уменьшении чего? :)

Comment: @Cypher масштаба

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вам надо работать с масштабом страницы, а не контурной карты, то попробуйте [таким макаром](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zqdYH/2/).

```js
var clientW = $(window).width();
var clientH = $(window).height();
$('#start span').text(clientW + ' x ' + clientH);
$(window).resize(function() {
  var curW = $(this).width();
  var curH = $(this).height();
  $('#current span').text(curW + ' x ' + curH).effect('pulsate', {
    times: 1
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Изменяйте масштаб (Ctrl + +, Ctrl + -, Ctrl + 0)</p>
<div id="start">Размер при загрузке: <span></span>
</div>
<div id="current">Размер изменен: <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
window.onresize = function(){
  //Код прекрасно работает во всех браузерах 
  //При изменениии масштаба/размера окна браузера
  var $WW_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; //Ширина экрана
  var $WW_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; //Высота экрана
}
```

Comment: масштаб и размер это вроде бы разные вещи

Comment: @danpetruk используя CSS вы контролируете CSS-пиксели а один CSS-пиксель равен нескольким или одному реальному в зависимости от масштаба не помню адрес но я уже объяснял про это форумчанам....