# jquery и масштаб страницы (увеличение страницы)

Tags: jquery, mobile

и снова я, со своими событиями!)) вы все мне очень сильно помогли, но у меня еще много вопросов )) я тут задался вопросом, а можно ли определить увеличение страницы (изменение масштаба), например, если на айпаднике открыть и увеличить масштаб, как это отследить?

Comment: тот же event resize сработать должен

Comment: resize будет реагировать при изменении размеров окна, а нужно реагировать на масштаб содержимого!

Comment: при масштабировании сработает resize. т.к. размеры окна изменятся.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это незнаю, но [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142313/javascript-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0) уже задавали.