# Как изменять атрибуты тэгов в Primefaces при событии масштабирования (изменения размеров окна)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, primefaces

Изначально я хочу что бы при изменении масштаба моей страницы изменялся размер всяких панелей и т.п. внутри. Сделал это через указание ширины в %, но в таком случае компьютер высчитывает сам ширину при изменении масштаба компоненты становятся не симметричными, а я хочу что бы всё ровно было. Дошёл до того что надо использовать Javascript + JQuery. [Вот здесь нашёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142313/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0) код, который приблизил меня к моей цели. Но когда я пытаюсь изменить атрибут style, или вообще любой другой атрибут в компоненте, будь это тег h:panelGrid или другой, ничего не происходит вообще, ноль эмоций, не реагирует вообще, а в обычном теге, допустим div можно изменить атрибут, вот с помощью этого кода, на который сослался выше.

Как изменять атрибуты в primefaces, помогите пожалуйста.